# How to solve this integral and what software I can use to find solution to it?

Tags: integration

How to solve this equation?
$$
\int_{-L}^{L}\frac{1}{(z^2 + x^2 )^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx
$$
[It's from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xJbt.png)

I tried to scan this with PhotoMath, but it appears that it can't solve such integrals. Also, I considered solving it with the Wolfram search engine, however, It doesn't show the process of solving. So my second question is what software or website I can use for these cases?

Comment: Do you know how to do $u$ substitution?

Comment: @healynr yes, i do

Comment: @healynr sorry i had typo there with degree, now I edited it

Comment: Then try $u^2=z^2+x^2$

Comment: **Hint:** Use the substitution $x=z\tan(u)$. Regarding your second question, you can try https://www.integral-calculator.com/ or the Pro version of Wolfram Alpha (I'd recommend trying to solve it before). Note that the solutions given there may not always be the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\tan^2(\alpha)+1 = \sec^2(\alpha)$ then multiplying both sides by $z^2$ gives
$$
\left(z\tan(\alpha)\right)^2+z^2 = z^2 \sec^2(\alpha) \implies \sqrt{\left(\color{purple}{z\tan(\alpha)}\right)^2+z^2 } = z \sec(\alpha)
$$
The key is to notice that $\sqrt{\left(\color{purple}{z\tan(\alpha)}\right)^2+z^2 }$ looks very similar to $\sqrt{\color{purple}{x}^2+z^2 }$, and since having "$z \sec(\alpha)$" in the denominator is easier to work with than a square root, we get the substitution $$\color{purple}{x}=\color{purple}{z\tan(\alpha)} \implies \mathrm{d}x = z \sec^2(\alpha)\,  \mathrm{d}\alpha$$
And thus
$\require{\cancel}$
\begin{align}
\int_{-L}^{L} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left(x^2 +z^2\right)^{\frac32}} & \overset{\color{darkblue}{\text{Even}}}{=}\color{darkblue}{2}\int_{\color{darkblue}{0}}^{L} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left(\sqrt{\color{purple}{x}^2 +z^2}\right)^{3}}\\
& \overset{\color{purple}{x}=\color{purple}{z\tan(\alpha)}}{=} 2\int_0^{\arctan\left(\frac{L}{z}\right)} \frac{z \sec^2(\alpha)\,  \mathrm{d}\alpha}{\left(z \sec(\alpha)\right)^3} \\
& \overset{\frac{1}{\sec(\alpha)}=\cos(\alpha)}{=} \frac{2}{z^2} \int_0^{\arctan\left(\frac{L}{z}\right)} \cos(\alpha) \, \mathrm{d}\alpha\\
& = \frac{2}{z^2} \sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{L}{z}\right)\right)
\end{align}
Recalling that $\tan^2(x) +1 = \sec^2(x)$, $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$ and $\cos(x)=\frac{1}{\sec(x)}$ we get
$$
\sin(x) = \sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)} = \sqrt{1- \frac{1}{\sec^2(x)}} = \sqrt{1- \frac{1}{\tan^2(x)+1}}
$$
we conclude
\begin{align}
&\int_{-L}^{L} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left(x^2 +z^2\right)^{\frac32}}  =  \frac{2}{z^2} \sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{L}{z}\right)\right) = \frac{2}{z^2}\sqrt{1- \frac{1}{\tan^2\left(\arctan\left(\frac{L}{z}\right)\right)+1}}\\
&=\frac{2}{z^2}\sqrt{1- \frac{1}{\left(\frac{L}{z}\right)^2+1}} = \frac{2}{z^2}\sqrt{1- \frac{z^2}{L^2 +z^2}} = \frac{2}{z^2}\sqrt{ \frac{L^2}{L^2 +z^2}} = \boxed{\frac{2L}{z^2\sqrt{z^2+L^2}}} 
\end{align}
as desired